# WooCommerce custom payment gateway: Just show an extra fee based on total order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, payment-method

I am using WooCommerce and Woocrypt and in the payment gateway for bitcoins I have added the following code in my gateway:

```
<b class="bold-titel">Amount</b>
<span class="ngh-blocktext copywrap-address"><?php echo $order->get_total(); ?></span>
```

Ex, it shows, total amount to pay is ex: 50$
but I wait it to show 55$ (50$ + 10% without adding the code i inserted further down here which change total cart)

I am wondring is it possible to add 10% fee to the get_total command?
i dont want to add 10% to the cart i only want the above code to display 10% extra.
I have this to advertise to the customer that he pays the 10% extra fee if they get free item on there order.

I got:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_fee_based_on_cart_total', 10, 1 ); function
custom_fee_based_on_cart_total( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // The percentage
    $percent = 10; // 10%
    // The cart total
    $cart_total = $cart->cart_contents_total; 

    // The conditional Calculation
    $fee = $cart_total >= 25 ? $cart_total * $percent / 100 : 0;

    if ( $fee != 0 ) 
        $cart->add_fee( __( "Gratuity", "woocommerce" ), $fee, false ); 
}
```

which adds fee to total order.

I don't want this, I only want the above code to show the get_total with 10% added to the total amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't display a message  in the related payment gateway description *(where you will need to set in the code below the correct payment Id)*.

*(You can also set this in the payment gateway description function instead)*

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_description', 'gateway_bacs_custom_fields', 20, 2 );
function gateway_bacs_custom_fields( $description, $payment_id ){
    // HERE below set the correct payment Id for your payment gateway
    if( 'bacs' === $payment_id )
    {
        $threshold_amount = 25; // threshold amount
        $percentage       = 10; // 10%

        $cart_subtotal    = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
        $cart_total       = WC()->cart->get_total('edit');

        if ( $cart_subtotal >= $threshold_amount ) {

            $message  = sprintf(
                __('%s You will pay %s of extra fee, if you get free item on your order.'),
                '<strong>' . __('Note:') . '</strong><br>',
                '<strong>' . wc_price( $cart_total * $percentage / 100 ) . '</strong>',
                $percentage . '%',
                wc_price($cart_total)
            );

            $message .= '<br><em>' . sprintf(
                __('This extra fee is %s of %s total order amount.'), $percentage . '%', wc_price($cart_total)
            ) . '</em>';

            $description .= '<div  class="message" style="padding:10px; margin-top:12px;; background-color: #fff; border: solid 1px #eee;">' . $message . '<div>';
        }
    }
    return $description;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

You could alternatively display in checkout a message notice:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    $threshold_amount = 25; // threshold amount
    $percentage       = 10; // 10%

    $cart_subtotal    = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
    $cart_total       = WC()->cart->get_total('edit');

    if ( $cart_subtotal >= $threshold_amount ) {
        wc_print_notice( sprintf(
            __('You will pay %s  of extra fee (%s of %s total order amount), if you get free item on your order.'),
            wc_price( $cart_total * $percentage / 100 ), $percentage . '%', wc_price($cart_total)
        ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]